# How does one edit the title of a question?

Tags: support, questions

I tried changing the title of this question: "How does iPhone icons are of same grid across all model" but was unable to. Is this a matter of accrued points or is there a conscious decision to maintain continuity?

Comment: You can delete your comment above too ... and I'll delete this.  That way it's all cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting usability issue. I didn't read the error message properly. I simply glanced at it and interpreted it as needing to put in 10 characters into the body of the text - NOT that I had to give a reason for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'was unable to'. You have enough site reputation score to be able to do so. Just click the 'edit' button underneath the question and change the title in the box. Like this:

[image]